# How can I create a 24 hour clock to run in the background?

Tags: c, multithreading, time, pthreads

I'm working with threads and I want to have a thread running in the background always keeping track of the time, except I'm treating every hour as a second so a 24 hour clock would complete a cycle in 24 seconds(after which the clock resets to 0) and I want a global variable to store the current "hour" so I can reference it in other threads.
I've looked around the internet and the time.h library but I couldn't find anything.

Can someone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: `while (1) { sleep(1); hour = (hour + 1) % 24; }`. Make `hour` global and all threads can access it. If that doesn't help then you need to show what you have tried and what specific problem you have with it.

Comment: To me, it's far from clear what you are trying to achieve. Just one note though: You already decided that threads is the right tool for the job. I'd question that decision.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's for an assignment. It should suffice.